# What can I use instead of Set() in Java?

Tags: javascript, java

The following code is in JavaScript to check if a pair of numbers in a set are equal to a specific sum.

```
function hasPairWithSum2(arr, sum){
    const mySet = new Set();
    const len = arr.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (mySet.has(arr[i]))
            return true;

        mySet.add(sum - arr[i]);
    }

    return false;
}
```

How can I do the same in Java? What is the alternative to Set()?

Comment: Java also has sets.

Comment: What is wrong with Set tho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code which uses HashSet() in Java.

```
public static boolean hasPairWithSum2(int arr[], int sum){
    HashSet<Integer>mySet=new HashSet<Integer>();
    int len = arr.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (mySet.contains(arr[i]))
            return true;

        mySet.add(sum - arr[i]);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: aww.. you did not make it an (almost) polyglot.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in Java is [`HashSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).